# How to interpret Java long as Lua number to convert epoch to human readable

Tags: java, date, lua, simpledateformat

*Program1*, written in Java, writes date to Redis in *EPOCH* format.

*Program2*, written in Lua, reads date from Redis in *EPOCH* format and attempts to convert it in human readable format.

The issue here is the epoch date is written to Redis as Java Long, as far as I know. And the conversion that I need to achieve in a LUA script works seamlessly in Java.

```
> import java.util.Date
> import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

> String redisEpochDate = "1451608885000"
> new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss").format(new Date(redisEpochDate.toLong))

> 01-01-2016 06:11:25
```

But when I try the same thing in Lua, I get wrong results.

```
> print(os.date("%x", tonumber("1451608885000")))
> 08/27/69
```

This is because of 3 trailing 0's in the epoch string. If I retry the same thing without the trailing 0's, I get correct results.

```
> print(os.date("%x", tonumber("1451608885")))
> 01/01/16
```

My question is how can deal with such a epoch string `1451608885000` in Lua to get desirable results because this is not something in my control?

*Please let me know if this is the right place for this question or this question needs to be expressed in a better way.*

Comment: What's wrong with `tonumber("1451608885000")/1000` ?

Comment: Is that the best we can do? I mean won't I need to be sure of the number of trailing 0's before attempting anything like that?

Comment: Sorry, the code should be `math.floor(tonumber("1451608885000")/1000)`

Comment: @codingkapoor: Yes, you should make sure. The Lua manual gives [a hint](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-os.time) about the meaning of the arguments to `os.date´ on certain systems (seconds since the epoch on POSIX and others), and the Java documentations [states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) that it can construct its dates from milliseconds since epoch. So there you have it: the difference is a factor of 1000.

Comment: Since Java has a good, modern and flexible API for dates and times — [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) — I would find it more natural to solve the problem on the Java side by writing seconds rather than milliseconds since the epoch to Redis.